# Is there a word or term for condemning/ judgmental rage?

Tags: expressions

I was simply looking for a better word/ term to replace condemning/ judgmental rage. More basically, I'm looking for a word/ term for when you are openly and angrily judging someone.

Comment: A "twitter tantrum". (;-))

Comment: Sounds like righteous indignation.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - Except that most often it isn't very righteous.

Comment: Are the judgments correct (or at least reasonable) but poorly expressed, or are the judgments completely baseless? Also, are the judgments being expressed directly to the person being judged, or is the person being judged being referred to in the third person? And finally, is the target always a single, specific person, or does this also apply when judging an entire group of people, an organization, an idea, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

**censure**

to criticize or reproach in a harsh or vehement manner

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/censure

Answer (score 2):

**Wrath** is described as a strong anger or deep indignation, retributory punishment for an offense or a crime, or *divine chastisement (or condemnation)* ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wrath)). The adjective is *wrathful*.

> There was no end to his wrath once he was aware that we would not take his advice.

A wrathful individual would be strongly judgmental and determined to express condemnation or a desire for punishment.

Answer (score 1):

**[reprimand](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reprimand)** (**M-W**)

*to reprove sharply or censure formally usually from a position of authority*.